# Mix CPP OpenCV / Main program C

Tags: c++, c, compilation, cmake

I got a main project based in C and I need to include a CPP function (that use OpenCV).
I was using a Cmake File to do so but that's not working anymore when i add the cpp file.

Here my Makefile

```
    cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.9)

project(tictactoe)

### Requierements

    find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED )
    include_directories(../Sources)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    include(CheckIncludeFiles)
include(CheckIncludeFileCXX)
### Subdirectories where the sources are

    FILE(GLOB MyCSources "../Sources/*.c")
ADD_LIBRARY(detect_tag ../Sources/detect_tag.cpp ../Sources/detect_tag.hpp)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(tictactoe  ${MyCSources} ../Sources/detect_tag.cpp ../Sources/detect_tag.hpp)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(tictactoe rt  ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Comment: Not your main problem but I'm pretty sure the `*.hpp` files don't need to be listed in the sources: they aren't compiled and if they aren't included then they aren't used ... so cmake doesn't need to know about them.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solved my problem using a wrapper : 
I've made a header file like wrapper.h and wrapper.cpp.

in the wrapper.h i got :

```
extern "C" my_function_through_wrapper();
```

in the wrapper.c i got :

```
#include file_where_my_function_if.h
extern "c" { 

my_function_through_wrapper(){
         my_function();
}

}
```

And that's it ! 
Indeed i've made and interface between the real mangling CPP and the C code. With the extern C my compiler know how to compile the wrapper file well that my C code can link to it. Then through the wrapper the CPP can be linked to the other CPP code using all the included librairies in CPP. Solved !